# Existence of nonergodic polygonal billiard

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, billiards

Let $P$ be a polygon in the plane. One can define the billiard flow on the unit tangent bundle of $P$, just following the trajectories of the billiard at speed one.

A standard conjecture is that a typical billiard flow is ergodic. But are there examples of irrational polygonal billiards for which the flow is known not to be ergodic ?

EDIT : It is obvious that in this sense every rational polygon is not ergodic. The good framework is irrational polygons, for which the question seems to be open.

Comment: A related question and answer on math.SE: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/6038/polygonal-billiards-and-uniform-distribution

Answer (score 8):

E. Gutkin, [Billiard dynamics: An updated survey with the emphasis on open problems](http://scitation.aip.org/content/aip/journal/chaos/22/2/10.1063/1.4729307) Chaos **22**, 026116 (2012) gives as open problem 8: *Give an example of an irrational but non-ergodic polygon.*  Some recent numerical results are given in J. Wang et al, [Non-ergodicity and localization of invariant measure for two colliding masses](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.7617v1.pdf) arxiv:1309.7617.

For rational polygons, there is a nice example of an L-shaped billiard and a non-ergodic direction in Fig 3 of L. Demarco [The conformal geometry of billiards](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/2011-48-01/S0273-0979-2010-01322-7/) Bull. AMS **48** 33-52 (2011).

**Update:** There is also literature on the somewhat related question of non-dense aperiodic orbits.  If a positive measure of orbits is not dense, the billiard is not ergodic.  G. A. Galpern [Non-periodic and not everywhere dense billiard trajectories in convex polygons and polyhedrons](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01211158#page-1) Commun. Math. Phys. **91** 187-211 (1983) gives examples of polygons with $n\geq 3$, including with irrational angles, which have non-dense aperiodic orbits.  G. W. Tokarsky [Galpern's triangle example](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00220-015-2336-6) Commun. Math. Phys. **335** 1211–1213 (2015) shows that the $n=3$ example orbit is in fact periodic, so the existence of a non-dense aperiodic orbit in a triangular billiard appears to be still open.

Comment: You are here dealing with non ergodic direction. Do you know if anything is known about the action on the phase space ?

Comment: @SelimG I'm not sure exactly what you are asking.  In a rational billiard, each trajectory visits only a finite number of directions, so is far from uniform in momentum space.  By "non-ergodic direction" I mean a direction in which the orbit is non-uniform in its available phase space: position space and the finite set of directions.

Comment: Yes, that is why I changed my question to irrational billiards :) Actually my question is exactly Gutkin's. Thanks for the link by the way.

Answer (score 4):

[The dynamics of billiard flows in rational polygons](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~lanneau/references/smillie2000.pdf) (J. Smillie, 2000): The billiard in a rational polygon is ergodic in "almost all" directions, more precisely, the Hausdorff dimension of the set of non-ergodic directions is at most 1/2.

Comment: An explicit example of Hausdorff dimension 1/2 may be found in Y. Cheung, "Hausdorff Dimension of the Set of Nonergodic Directions", Ann Math 158, 661-678 (2003).

Answer (score 2):

There are examples in the slit torus. 
Prof. Smillie explains this in:
http://www2.warwick.ac.uk/fac/sci/maths/people/staff/john_smillie/course/notes14february.pdf

Comment: As for Carl, Smillie seems to deal with specific directions. I was wondering about the action on the phase space.

Answer (score 2):

Numerical evidences for non-ergodic irrational triangles may be found in

Lima, Rodríguez-Pérez and de Aguiar, Phys. Rev. E 87, 062902 (2013).